# Matlab Average Two Fourier transforms with different frequency vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, fft, average

Suppose I have two power spectrum vectors PS1 and PS2 which were created using fft and then taking only the positive frequency values and squaring the fft values (complex conjugate really).

Suppose also that the corresponding frequency values for PS1 and PS2 are different. E.g. PS1(10) might correspond to 10 Hz and PS2(10) might correspond to 10.5 Hz.

I want to have an average of these two (and more) power spectra. How would I best create such an average? It is fine if the PS_ave is a longer vector than any of the original power spectra, so long as there is a corresponding frequency vector. So, it might be that PS_ave(11) corresponds to 10.25 Hz, and this value should probably be the average of PS1(10) and PS2(10). All ideas are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: could you please include some examples or figures of what you'd like achieving?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using `interp1`, which can interpolate within one signal to match frequencies for another spectrum. The following example illustrates this:

```
v1 =1;
t1 = [0:0.1:10];
sig1 = sin(2*pi*t1*v1).*exp(-0.5*t1)/length(t1);
v2 = 0.5;
t2 = [0:0.2:10];
sig2 = cos(2*pi*t2*v2).*exp(-0.5*t2)/length(t2);
s1= fft(sig1);
s1 = s1(1:end/2);
f1 = [0:length(s1)-1]*(1/max(t1));
s2= fft(sig2); 
s2 = s2(1:end/2);
f2 = [0:length(s2)-1]*(1/max(t2));
p1 = abs(s1);
p2 = abs(s2);

% Now average using interpolation to find points in the longer vector matching the shorter

p1_interp = interp1(f1,p1,f2);
power_avg = mean([p2; p1_interp],1)

hold on, plot(f2,power_avg,'r')
```

Here's the result (red = avg power):

[image]